# Using CKEditor5 Custom Build in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ckeditor

I'm building a sort of article editor, for this I'm using the [Angular Integration](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html) for CKEditor5; following the documentation I can correctly use the `ClassicEditor` build with the `ckeditor` component.

These are my files:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-article',
  templateUrl: './edit-article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-article.component.scss']
})
export class EditArticleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
  articleForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Template

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
         <label for="">Content</label>
         <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" id="editor" class="blue-scroll--light" formControlName="content"></ckeditor>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the `ClassicEditor` build referenced in that guide does not include many plugins, so I'm trying to add some of them, like text alignment, font color, font size, etc.

It seems that I need to create a **custom build** which includes all of the desired features and then reference that build instead of the `ClassicEditor` in my typescript file if I understand correctly, so I went ahead and used their [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) to create a build with all the plugins already included, but after that I'm not sure how to proceed and the documentation isn't really clear.

As far as I understand, I need to add the `build` folder inside my Angular App and then import the `ckeditor.js` file in my component, like this:

```
import * as Editor from '../../../../../core/libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';
```

and change the declaration of the Editor to use that import instead of the `ClassicEditor`, so:

```
public Editor = Editor;
```

However as soon as I make that change I'm no longer able to even run the app, since I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated. Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules

CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated. Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules

    at Object.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:5)
    at Object.push../src/app/core/libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js (ckeditor.js:5)
    at i (ckeditor.js:5)
    at Module.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:5)
    at i (ckeditor.js:5)
    at push../src/app/core/libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js (ckeditor.js:5)
    at ckeditor.js:5
    at ckeditor.js:5
    at Object../src/app/core/libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js (ckeditor.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at zone.js:913
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:30885)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Again, the docs say it is due to multiple imports being made but I don't understand how since I'm only using the `ckeditor.js` file that comes in the build I just generated, which works fine if referenced in a plain HTML file.

**Can someone provide an example on how to successfully make a Custom Build work in a Angular App?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while, I found that the problem seems to be that I had another build imported in a different module of my application.

So I was only using the custom build inside my `EditArticle` component by importing and using that file, but I also had other components on other modules that were importing and using the `ClassicEditor` build that I installed through NPM, which looks like it was causing the error.

The fix was not to **remove** the `ClassicEditor` package nor removing the `import ClassicEditor` statement, but just making sure that that specific import was not being used anywhere else in the app, since I guess during compilation Angular removes all unused imports.

Once I did this, the application ran fine with my custom build.

Just to clear it up, I can have these two imports on the same file or multiple components

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import * as Editor from 'src/app/core/libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';
```

But I should only be using one of them on the entire app, so if I have an Editor on `Component1` and on `Component2`, I can have both builds *imported*, but on the declaration of the Editor property I should only use one, and it should be the same one on every component the app uses, so:

*This works*

*Component1*

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import * as Editor from 'src/app/core/libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';

public Editor = Editor;
```

Component2

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import * as Editor from 'src/app/core/libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';

public Editor = Editor;
```

*This **WON'T** work*

*Component1*

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import * as Editor from 'src/app/core/libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';

public Editor = Editor;
```

Component2

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import * as Editor from 'src/app/core/libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';

public Editor = ClassicEditor;
```

You can of course just remove the unused build from the imports altogether and that'll work too. Just again, make sure you use the same build on all the application

Comment: I don't see any difference between Components 1 and 2 under "This works" and  "This WON'T work".  Asidefrom the assignment of your `public Editor`

Comment: @ColdCerberus that's exactly the point... Just declaring the import of different editor builds on the app won't cause any issues, but actually assigning  both of the builds, even if it is on different components will break the app

Comment: Understood. I am currently using the generated build also from the online tool. The problem I have is The default toolbar does not show by default (There is no toolbar at all by default). So I had to manually add the config to show it. Also, a couple of plugins I added were `code` and `codeblock`. Adding them to the config worked but the `image` toolbar item did not work even if I added it during building with the online tool.

How did you properly integrate your custom build? At the first place, I shouldn't be making my config since I defined the default toolbar with the online builder.

Comment: Did you import it as a regular library in your project? I just have it on a `lib` folder, I import de js file from there as `Editor` and just assign it, after that it just works as if I was just using the classic build

Answer (score 0):

```
     console.log(this.ckEditorClassic.builtinPlugins.map( plugin => plugin.pluginName ));
  }

This will give you the list of plugins in the custom build. 
My sample has :
["Alignment", "AutoImage", "Autoformat", "Autosave", "BlockQuote", "Bold", "CodeBlock", "Essentials", "ExportPdf", "ExportWord", "FontBackgroundColor", "FontColor", "FontFamily", "FontSize", "Heading", "Highlight", "HorizontalLine", "Image", "ImageCaption", "ImageInsert", "ImageResize", "ImageStyle", "ImageToolbar", "ImageUpload", "Indent", "IndentBlock", "Italic", "Link", "List", "Markdown", "MathType", "MediaEmbed", "MediaEmbedToolbar", "PageBreak", "Paragraph", "PasteFromOffice", "SpecialCharacters", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "Strikethrough", "Subscript", "Superscript", "Table", "TextTransformation", "WordCount"]


take the displayed list within [] and replace xxxx with it.

<ckeditor [config]="{toolbar:[xxxx] }"
```